# Sort list by passing string value for wanted field, and second sort by date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have a Javascript list

```
var list = [
{ date: "2005-04-01", position: 12, worker: "John",     prop: "k11" },
{ date: "2006-02-01", position: 72, worker: "John",     prop: "k12" },
{ date: "2005-09-06", position: 42, worker: "Aleks",    prop: "k43" },
{ date: "2004-07-02", position: 12, worker: "Mark",     prop: "k12" },
];
```

I would like to create  a sort function like list.sort('position','12') that is going to sort list by value '12' for position field and give output.

date: "2005-04-01", position: 12, worker: "John",   prop: "k11"

date: "2004-07-02", position: 12, worker: "Mark",   prop: "k12"

date: "2006-02-01", position: 72, worker: "John",   prop: "k12"

date: "2005-09-06", position: 42, worker: "Aleks",  prop: "k43"

but you can also call it like list.sort('worker','John') and it will also sort it by date after worker sort

Comment: Can include `js` tried at Question ?

Comment: What type of sorting algorithm is this?

Comment: Sounds very strange, here's a start for you -> **https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/1yLuufhd/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proposal with a privileged sorting for the given key/value pair.

Features:

- Closure for the privileged key/value, returns
- Function for sorting

  - Moves found key/value to top
  - Sort otherwise by date descending

```js
var list = [
    { date: "2005-04-01", position: 12, worker: "John", prop: "k11" },
    { date: "2006-02-01", position: 72, worker: "John", prop: "k12" },
    { date: "2005-09-06", position: 42, worker: "Aleks", prop: "k43" },
    { date: "2004-07-02", position: 12, worker: "Mark", prop: "k12" },
];

function setCondition(condition) {
    var key = Object.keys(condition)[0],
        value = condition[key];
    return function (a, b) {
        function x(o) { return -(o[key] === value); }
        return x(a) - x(b) || b.date.localeCompare(a.date);
    }
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(list.sort(setCondition({ position: 12 })), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(list.sort(setCondition({ worker: 'John' })), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and quick answer, it works perfectly !

Comment: @user126939, if you find this answer usefull, then vote it up and/or accept the answer, because stackoverflow is working like this. please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

If a new reference is fine, find all matches, find all non-matches, concat these two arrays

```
function bringToTop(arrOfObj, prop, val) {
    return arrOfObj.filter(e => e[prop] === val).concat(
        arrOfObj.filter(e => e[prop] !== val)
    );
}
```

e.g.

```
var arr = [
    {foo: 0, bar: 0, baz: 'fizz'},
    {foo: 0, bar: 1, baz: 'buzz'},
    {foo: 1, bar: 0, baz: 'fizz'},
    {foo: 1, bar: 1, baz: 'buzz'}
];

bringToTop(arr, 'baz', 'buzz');
/*
[
    {foo: 0, bar: 1, baz: 'buzz'},
    {foo: 1, bar: 1, baz: 'buzz'},
    {foo: 0, bar: 0, baz: 'fizz'},
    {foo: 1, bar: 0, baz: 'fizz'}
]
*/
```

---

If you want the same ref, take this result, empty your original then push in the result

```
var res = bringToTop(arr, 'baz', 'buzz');
arr.length = 0;
Array.prototype.push.apply(arr, res);
```